# spring 3 mvc requestmapping dynamic param problem

Tags: spring, request, restful-url, mapping

I have the following code which works fine with 
http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldSpring3/forms/helloworld

but i want to have url have some thing like this

http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldSpring3/forms/helloworld/locname_here/locid_here

I found that adding this @RequestMapping("/helloworld/**") will work but when i try to access

http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldSpring3/forms/helloworld/locname_here/locid_here

it is not found.

Web.xml entry as follows

```
<servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/forms/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Mapping bean entry

```
@RequestMapping("/helloworld/**")
       public ModelAndView helloWord(){
              String message = "Hello World, Spring 3.0!";
              return new ModelAndView("helloworld", "message",message);
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/helloworld")
public class HelloWorldController{

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{locname_here}/{locid_here}")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld(@PathVariable String locname_here, @PathVariable long locid_here) {
        //Logic
    }

}
```

The above code works for your requirement.

Comment: it is not working it says "The requested resource () is not available."

Comment: Please send your sample URLs you try from your jsp. It will help me understand your requirement better

Comment: What is the controller mapping. If the controller mapping contains helloworld like the code below then the method need not have the same mapping @RequestMapping("/helloworld") public class HelloWorldController {...

Comment: The only mapping i have is as follows

@RequestMapping(value = "/helloworld/{locname_here}/{locid_here}")

Comment: URL I USED 
http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldSpring3/forms/helloworld/locname_here/123

Comment: Can I have a look at your controller class

Comment: @Controller
public class HelloWorldController {
   
  @RequestMapping(value = "/helloworld/{locname_here}/{locid_here}")
     public ModelAndView helloWorld(@PathVariable String locname_here, @PathVariable long locid_here) {
     String message = "Hello World, Spring 3.0!";
        return new ModelAndView("helloworld", "message",message);
 }
  }

Comment: I have modified the response. This is how it works on my machine

Comment: I have made the changes but i c still no luck :(
http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldSpring3/form/helloworld/name/1233

but following working
http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldSpring3/form/helloworld

Comment: Request you to delete all the cache from the container, rebuild and try the one in the edited response. I am not able to figure out what will be the problem as it works on my machine.